# Question about mobile friendly alternative for background-attachment?

Tags: html, css

I was doing a project in fcc there they told an mobile friendly alternate to background-attachment
Question #1
What is the use of ::before
Question 2
What is the use of z-index?

```
body::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: var(--color-darkblue);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      115deg,
      rgba(58, 58, 158, 0.8),
      rgba(136, 136, 206, 0.7)
    ),
    url(backgroundimage.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a search engine for simple questions like "What is the use of z-index" the next time.

Question 1: the `::before` is a so called pseudo-element. It is used to add some content before the selected element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before.

Question 2: the z-index is most commonly used to make elements overlap and generally an element with a higher z-index is positioned before one with a lower z-index https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index. To get a better understanding on how elements overlap, you should have a look at the stacking context.

Unfortunately your question is not really clear but I'm assuming that you don't really understand what is going on in your example.

When you use `position fixed` the element is taken out of the document-flow. This means that declarations like `height: 100%` `width: 100%` are relative to the parent. If you would use `body {...}` instead of `body::before{...}` the parent would be your html element.
If you apply `position: fixed` to your body and take it out of the document-flow, the html will have no in-flow elements which means that the height of the html-element will be 0.
Since your bodys height would be 100% of it's parents height(your html-element) it would also be 0.

That is why in your example `body::before` is used. This behaves like a first child of body. So the declarations `height:100%` and `width:100%` will be relative to your body-element instead of your html-element.

Comment: Thanks for your response this really helped me to understand the use of body::before it was really irritating me